# Curvature of the complex projective space.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, several-complex-variables, submanifold

> Define a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb C^{n+1} - \{0\}$ in the following way: If $Z \in \mathbb C^{n+1}-\{0\}$ and $V,W \in T_Z(\mathbb C^{n+1}-\{0\})$, $$\langle V,W \rangle_Z = \frac{\text{Real}(V,W)}{(Z,Z)}.$$
>   Observe that hte mteric $\langle \,,\,\rangle$ restricted to $S^{2n+1} \subset \mathbb C^{n+1}-\{0\}$ coincides with the metric induced from $\mathbb R^{2n+2}$.
>
> (b) Show that, in this metric, the sectional curvature of $\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C)$ is given by $$K(\sigma)=1+3\cos^2 \varphi,$$ where $\sigma$ is generated by the orthonormal pair $X,Y, \cos \varphi=\left\langle \overline X,i\overline Y\right\rangle$, and $\overline X,\overline Y$ are the horizontal lifts of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. In particular, $1 \le K(\sigma) \le 4$.

This is Exercise 8.12 of Riemannian Geometry by do Carmo. Yes, there is a part (a) but I did not print it here because my question here concerns only part (b).

Also, I realize that $P^n(\mathbb C)$ is the complex projective space of complex dimension $n$ and is denoted in other textbooks as $\mathbb CP^n$.

> *Hint for (b)*: Let $Z$ be the position vector describing $S^{2n+1}$. Since $(\frac d{d\theta}e^{i\theta}Z)_{\theta=0}=iZ$, $iZ \in T_Z(S^{2n+1})$ and is vertical. Let $\overline \nabla$ be the Riemannian connection of $\mathbb R^{2n+2} \approx \mathbb C^{n+1}$ and $X,Y \in \mathcal X(P^n(\mathbb C))$. Take $\alpha : (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to S^{2n+1}$ with $\alpha(0)=Z$, $\alpha'(0)-\overline X$. Then
>   \begin{align}
> (\overline \nabla_{\overline X}iZ)_Z &= \frac d{dt} iZ \circ \alpha(t))\Big\vert_{t=0} \\ 
> &= \frac d{dt} i\alpha(t) \Big\vert_{t=0} = i\alpha'(0)=i\overline X.
> \end{align}
>   Therefore,
>   \begin{align}
> \left\langle [\overline X,\overline Y],iZ \right\rangle &= \left\langle \overline \nabla_{\overline X}\overline Y-\overline \nabla_{\overline Y}\overline X,iZ \right\rangle \\ 
> &= -\left\langle i\overline X,\overline Y \right\rangle + \left\langle i\overline Y,\overline X \right\rangle = 2\cos \varphi.
> \end{align}
>   Now use Exercise 10(b).

I am trying to provide the details of the last line: "Now use Exercise 10(b)". Exercise 8.10(b) merely asserts O'Neill's formula:

> $$
> K(\sigma)=\overline K(\overline \sigma) + \frac 34 \left|[\overline X,\overline Y]^v \right|^2
> $$

So my approach is as follows:
$$
K(\sigma)=\overline K(\overline \sigma) + \frac 34 \left|[\overline X,\overline Y]^v \right|^2 
= 1 + \frac 34 \left|[\overline X,\overline Y]^v \right|^2 
$$
and
$$
1+3\cos^2 \varphi = 1+\frac 34 |2 \cos \varphi|^2 = 1+\frac 34 \left| \left\langle [\overline X,\overline Y],iZ \right\rangle \right|^2.
$$
But I am not sure how to link these together by establishing 
$$
\left|[\overline X,\overline Y]^v \right| = \left| \left\langle [\overline X,\overline Y],iZ \right\rangle \right|.
$$
Clearly, $[\overline X,\overline Y]^v$ is a vertical field, so $\left\langle [\overline X,\overline Y],iZ \right\rangle$ has to be vertical as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $\langle [\overline{X},\overline{Y}], iZ\rangle$ is not vertical - it is not even a vector field!

The claim (which I leave to you) that you need to establish to link the two is the following:

**Claim**:  $iZ$ is a unit vector which spans the vertical space.

Believeing this claim, the point is that $\left(\left\langle [\overline{X},\overline{Y}], iZ\right\rangle\right) i Z$ is the projection of $[\overline{X},\overline{Y}]$ to the vertical subspace.  That is, $\left(\left\langle [\overline{X},\overline{Y}], iZ\right\rangle\right) i Z = [\overline{X},\overline{Y}]^v.$  Taking lengths of both sides of this equality gives the equality you need.

Comment: Let me know if you have trouble proving the claim, and then I can provide more details

Comment: The first line of the textbook's given hint says "Let $Z$ be the position vector describing $S^{2n+1}$." Because $S^{2n+1}$ is a unit sphere, $|Z|=1$. And obviously $|i|=1$. So $|iZ|=|i||Z|=1\cdot 1=1$. I am still unsure about the part why $iZ \in T_Z(S^{2n+1})$ is vertical, mostly because my fundamental understanding of the "fiber"--let alone a vector being orthogonal to said fiber so that said vector is *horizontal*--is shaky.

Comment: I don't have Do Carmo with me right now, can you remind me his definition of being vertical?  As well as his definition of $\mathbb{C}P^n$?  For me, $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is the quotient of $S^{2n+1}$ by the natural $S^1$ action coming from complex multiplication.  I define "vertical" by "kernel of the differential $\pi_\ast:T_ p S^{2n+1}\rightarrow T_{\pi(p)}\mathbb{C}P^n$.  Then, the curve $e^{it} Z$ is on $S^{2n+1}$ and has derivative $iZ$.  Then, almost by definition, $\pi(e^{it} Z)$ is constant, so $iZ$ is in the kernel of the differential map.

Comment: Here are the original problems (8.8-8.12) of do Carmo in this PDF: http://docdro.id/hA13UgA. 8.8 defines the *vertical vector*, 8.9 mentions *horizontal lift*, and 8.11 introduces the notion of the compex projective space $P^n(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: I see.  Do Carmo's definition of vertical is equivalent to the one I gave above.  If $\gamma(t)$ is in the fiber, then $f(\gamma(t))$ is constant so $f_\ast \gamma'(0) = 0$.  Then count dimensions to get the other direction.  His definition is of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ via excercise 10c is almost verbatim what mine is.  Are you still having issues?

Comment: I'm still having issues, unfortunately ... When you asked me to "count the dimensions", will that address the claim that $iZ$ spans the vertical space? Would I have to know the dimension of the fiber $f^{-1}(p)=F_p$? Also, I believe I already addressed above that $iZ$ is a unit vector but I have not heard yet if you agree or disagree with that assessment. (By the way, there is no Exercise 10(c), but perhaps you are referring to Exercise 11 for the definition of $P^n(\mathbb C)$.)

Comment: First, yes, counting dimensions will address the claim.  From 11c (not 10c, as you pointed out) the fiber above the point $[Z]\in \mathbb{C}P^n$ is the set of all points of the form $e^{i\theta} Z$ in $S^{2n+1}$.  For fixed $Z$, this is one dimensional (in fact, a great circle on $S^{2n+1}$).  Also, I agree with your calculation that $iZ$ is a unit vector.

Comment: I plan to think more about establishing the claim on my own, but in doing so I know that my calculation for sectional curvature will fall into place. In the meantime, may I ask another question from this same problem? (I also meant to ask the following question in my original post.)

Comment: I am also stuck at justifying the second step of the expression of $(\overline \nabla_{\overline X} iZ)_Z$ in the given hint: $$\left\langle \overline \nabla_{\overline X}\overline Y-\overline \nabla_{\overline Y}\overline X,iZ \right\rangle = -\left\langle i\overline X,\overline Y \right\rangle + \left\langle i\overline Y,\overline X \right\rangle.$$ It seems to me that $Z$ leaves $\alpha(t)$ fixed but how is this so? There is of course $\alpha(0)=Z$ and $\alpha'(0)=\overline X$, the latter of which was already used to justify the last equality. Do you possibly have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Well, $\langle \overline{Y}, iZ\rangle = 0$ since $iZ$ is vertical and $\overline{Y}$ is horizontal.  So, $X\langle \overline{Y}, iZ\rangle = 0$, so   $\langle\overline{\nabla}_X \overline{Y}, iZ\rangle = - \langle \overline{Y}, \nabla_X iZ\rangle.$  Now use the computation above in the book.  For that computation, the first equality is because you have the usual Euclidean connection.  Then next equality $Z\circ \alpha(t)  = \alpha(t)$ is because $Z$ is literally the position vector.

Comment: In my previous comment, I made a careless mistake and copy-pasted the wrong equality! I knew already to use the usual properties of Riemannian connections (symmetry; compatibility with Riemannian metric) while exploiting the properties of vertical and horizontal fields, as well as $(\overline \nabla_{\overline X} iZ)_Z=i\overline X$. I meant to actually copy-paste $$\frac d{dt}iZ \circ \alpha(t)) = \frac d{dt} i\alpha(t)$$ and ask why that was true, which you addressed in the last sentence of your latest comment. That was my only other question. Sorry for my confusing comment above.